# Characterization of normal $p$-complements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number. $N$ is a normal $p$-complement of a finite group $G$ if and only if $O_{p'}(G)=N=O^p(G)$.

Here $O_{p'}(G)$ is the largest normal subgroup whose prime divisors lie in $\mathbb P\setminus \{p\}$ and $O^p(G)$ is the smallest normal subgroup whose factor group is a $p$-group.

**My attempt:** First assume that $O_{p'}(G)=N=O^p(G)$ and let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then $N$ is a normal subgroup and $P\cap N=1$. Thus, $|PN|=|G|$. Also, as $PN$ is a subgroup because $N$ is normal. Thus, $G=PN$ and so $N$ is a normal $p$-complement of $G$.

Conversely, let $N$ be a normal $p$-complement of $G$. Then there exists be a Sylow $p$-subgroup  $P$ of $G$ such that $G=PN$ and $P\cap N=1$.

It is easy to see that prime divisors of $N$ lie in $\mathbb P\setminus \{p\}$. Next, let $H$ be another subgroup whose prime divisors lie in $\mathbb P\setminus \{p\}$. Then for each $h\in H$, there exists $x\in P, y\in N$ such that $h=xy$. Since orders of $x$ and $y$ are coprime, so $|h|=|x| |y|$. In particular, $|x|$ divides $|h|$ and so $x=1$. Thus, $h=y\in N$. We have thus shown that $H\subseteq N$. It follows that $O_{p'}(G)=N$.

Finally, the factor group $G/N$ is of course a $p$-group. We're left to show that if $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/K$ is a $p$-group, then $N\subseteq K$.

---

I can't figure out how to complete this.

---

**Edit:** Since $|G/K|\leq |G/N|$, we have that $|N|\leq |K|$. But this doesn't necessarily mean that $N\subseteq K$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N \not\le K$ then $NK/K$ would be a nontrivial $p'$-subgroup of the $p$-group $G/K$, contradiction.

Comment: Why is $NK/N$ a $p'$-subgroup? We have $|NK/N|= |K|/|N\cap K|$, the latter can have $p$ as a prime factor. For example, if $|G|=p^2q^2, |N|=q^2, |K|=pq^2$, then?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $NK/K$.

Comment: Oh, yes. This makes sense. Thank you!